# How to simplify the following trigonometry expression such that the number of used characters is minimal?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How to simplify the following trigonometry expression such that the number of used characters is minimal?

```
(13*Cos[t] - 5*Cos[2*t] - 2*Cos[3*t] - Cos[4*t])/4
```

The question sounds weird because I ask for the minimal number of used characters, but it is not a typo. The number of used characters must be minimal because the plotter needs short expression. Please ignore the computation performance for this case.

Comment: Perhaps you should replace minimum character count by minimum computing effort?

Comment: What exactly is this "plotter" you speak of that gives you this peculiar requirement?

Comment: @J.M.: In addition to the plotter constraint, the fewer the number of used characters is, the easier it is for us to remember the expression. Please see [the sixth curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html). That is why I am interested to simplify the expression as minimal as possible.

Comment: Oh, it's for the heart curve? You might be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12098), then... also, "the easier it is for us to remember the expression." - you can't look up stuff where you are?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know about the expression with "minimal chracters", but the following is the version I like, since you only have to evaluate the cosine once as a common subexpression:

```
HornerForm[(13 Cos[t] - 5 Cos[2 t] - 2 Cos[3 t] - Cos[4 t])/4 /.
           Cos[n_Integer  t] :> ChebyshevT[n, Cos[t]], Cos[t]]

1 + Cos[t] (19/4 + Cos[t] (-(1/2) + (-2 - 2 Cos[t]) Cos[t]))
```

---

As Yves notes, you can now use a scoping construct (i.e. any of `Block[]`/`Module[]`/`With[]`) to isolate the common subexpression. For instance:

```
With[{ct = Cos[t]}, 1 + ct (19/2 - ct (1 + 4 ct (1 + ct)))/2]
```

Comment: Good one, many-gravatared one! For speed, one might perhaps further save on cycles with a `With[{cos=Cos[t]},...]` or similar.

Comment: Yes, I had scoping with something like `With[]` in mind when I said "evaluate the cosine once as a common subexpression". Putting the expression in Horner form additionally cuts down on the multiplications needed.

Comment: Just wanted to suggest you include that verbatim in the answer for educational purposes.

Comment: Ah, I'm slow today. Of course...

Comment: Same thing here: ["es ist zu heiß..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIGNUwCsEl4)  (it is too hot).

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure I understand the question - surely there must be some syntax rules for the expression sent to the plotter. Anyway, the shortest *Mathematica* expression I can think of is:

```
{-13, 5, 2, 1}.Cos[{1, 2, 3, 4} t]/-4
```

Comment: Why not `-{-13, 5, 2, 1}.Cos[Range[4] t]/4`? :)

Comment: @J.M. good point! I considered `Range` but decided it was longer than writing the list out in full. This is what happens when you try to count to 9 before the first coffee of the day :-)

Answer (score 3):

One idea is to use something like

```
FullSimplify[
  (13*Cos[t] - 5*Cos[2*t] - 2*Cos[3*t] - Cos[4*t])/4
  , ComplexityFunction -> Composition[StringLength, ToString, InputForm]
]
```

which instructs `FullSimplify` to optimize the number of input characters for the expression. In this case it doesn't get any shorter though.