# How to transform the result of this integral into powers of $\sin\,x$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

I  want to calculate the integral
$I = \displaystyle\int{\cos ^5 x\, \mathrm dx}$. Using the variable  $t = \sin x$, I get
$$I = \sin x - \frac{2}{3}\sin^3 x + \frac{1}{5}\sin^5 x + C.$$
With *Mathematica*, when I input

```
 Integrate[Cos[x]^5, x]
```

I get

```
(5 Sin[x])/8 + 5/48 Sin[3 x] + 1/80 Sin[5 x]
```

How to format the result in the form?  $$I = \sin x - \frac{2}{3}\sin^3 x + \frac{1}{5}\sin^5 x.$$

Similar questions with integral $I =\displaystyle \int{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + \sin x + \cos x}}$ by setting $t = \tan\dfrac{x}{2}$, we have $I = \ln \left|1 + \tan\dfrac{x}{2}\right|$. I tried

```
(Integrate[1/(1 + Sin[x] - Cos[x]), x] // TrigExpand) /. {Sin[x] -> 
     2*Tan[x/2]/(1 + Tan[x/2]^2), 
    Cos[x] -> (1 - Tan[x/2]^2)/(1 + Tan[x/2]^2)} // 
  Simplify // TraditionalForm
```

and get the result `log(sin(x/2)+cos(x/2))-log(cos(x/2)).` 
How to format the result in the form?
$$I = \ln \left|1 + \tan\dfrac{x}{2}\right|$$.

Comment: I am sorry when I ask the question.

Comment: using `Integrate[Cos[x]^5, x] // TrigExpand // convert[#, Sin[x]] &` using the `convert` function defined in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/434/how-to-express-trigonometric-equation-in-terms-of-of-given-trigonometric-functio

Comment: @chris `TrigExpand` is becoming one of my most favorite functions even though I am yet to utilize it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you expand your expression in terms of elementary trig functions

```
Integrate[Cos[x]^5, x] // TrigExpand

(5 Sin[x])/8 + 5/16 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x] + 1/16 Cos[x]^4 Sin[x] - (
 5 Sin[x]^3)/48 - 1/8 Cos[x]^2 Sin[x]^3 + Sin[x]^5/80
```

you will see only even powers of Cos - so it's straightforward to replace it like this:

```
(Integrate[Cos[x]^5, x] // TrigExpand) /. 
   Cos[x] -> Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]^2] // Simplify // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I'll answer with a more general module I've done for converting trig expressions. An overkill here, but anyway:

```
trigSet[exp_, inTerm_] := 
 Module[{trigSyms, rels, set, setRep, setRep1, toLow, oneInTermsOf, allInTermsOf, fq, 
          ruleAll, convert},

  trigSyms = {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot, Sec, Csc};
  rels     = {csc sin == 1, cos^2 + sin^2 == 1, 1 == cos sec, tan == sin/cos, cot tan == 1};
  set      = ToExpression /@ ToLowerCase /@ SymbolName /@ trigSyms;
  setRep   = Thread[set -> (ToExpression /@ (StringJoin[#, "[x_]"] & /@ ToString /@ set))];
  setRep1  = Thread[set -> (ToExpression /@ (StringJoin[#, "[x]"] & /@ ToString /@ set))];
  toLow    = Thread[trigSyms -> set];

  oneInTermsOf[one_, of_] :=  Solve[rels, {one}, Complement[set, {one, of}]];
  allInTermsOf[of_] :=  Flatten[oneInTermsOf[#, of] & /@ Complement[set, {of}]];
  fq[x_, y_] := FreeQ[x, Alternatives @@ Complement[set, {y}]];
  ruleAll[of_] := Rule @@@ Transpose[{#[[1]] /. setRep, #[[2]] /. setRep1} &@
                                                     Transpose@(List @@@ allInTermsOf[of])];
  convert[expr_, inTerms_] := FullSimplify@ Union@Select[
      Flatten@NestWhile[# /. (List /@ ruleAll[inTerms]) &, {TrigExpand[expr] /. 
           toLow }, ! Or @@ (fq[#, inTerms] & /@ Flatten@#) &], fq[#, inTerms] &];
  HoldForm[ Evaluate@convert[exp, inTerm]] /. (Reverse /@ toLow)
  ]

  trigSet[(5 Sin[x])/8 + 5/48 Sin[3 x] + 1/80 Sin[5 x], sin]
  (*
  -> {Sin[x]-(2 Sin[x]^3)/3+Sin[x]^5/5}
  *)
```

Test it with more difficult expressions:

```
trigSet[Cos[3 x] - Tan[2 x] + Cot[3 x]^2, sin]
```

**Edit**

Depending on your expression, because of the signs in the radicals, you could need more than one "converted" one to cover the whole domain. For example:

```
s = Cos[x] Sin[x];
s0 = trigSet[s, sin]
s1 = FullSimplify[Reduce[# == s, x, Reals] & /@ ReleaseHold[s0] /. _Equal -> False]
(*
{-Sin[x] Sqrt[1-Sin[x]^2],Sin[x] Sqrt[1-Sin[x]^2]}

{C[1] \[Element] Integers && 
      ((Pi + x > 2 Pi  C[1] && Pi + 2 x <= 4 Pi C[1]) || Pi/2 <= x - 2 Pi C[1] < Pi),
 C[1] \[Element] Integers &&
       -(Pi/2) <= x - 2 \[Pi] C[1] <= Pi/2}

*)
```

Still working in automating this last process, but you can plot it like:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{-Sin[x] Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]^2], 
                      Resolve[Exists[C[1], Element[C[1], Integers], 
                              ((Pi + x > 2 Pi  C[1] && Pi + 2 x <= 4 Pi C[1]) || 
                                Pi/2 <= x - 2 Pi C[1] < Pi)]]}, 
                    {Sin[x] Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]^2], 
                       Resolve[Exists[C[1], Element[C[1], Integers],
                             -(Pi/2) <= x - 2 \[Pi] C[1] <= Pi/2]]}}];
Plot[{f[x], Sin[x] Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Dashed, Red}, Blue, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: how does this differ from Simon's answer? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/434/how-to-express-trigonometric-equation-in-terms-of-of-given-trigonometric-functio

Comment: @chris no idea. Probably in that this code is mine and one can get the domains of validity of each function in case you have more than one result (in different intervals)

Comment: and why does it return a list?

Comment: @chris Because the signs of radicals are taken in account. Try `trigSet[Sin[x] Cos[x], sin]` and plot the results

Comment: With trigSet[Cos[x]^4 - Cos[x/2]^2, cos], I get
\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"1", "-", 
RowBox[{"9", " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
FractionBox["x", "2"], "]"}], "2"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"24", " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
FractionBox["x", "2"], "]"}], "4"]}], "-", 
RowBox[{"32", " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
FractionBox["x", "2"], "]"}], "6"]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"16", " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
FractionBox["x", "2"], "]"}], "8"]}]}], "}"}],
HoldForm]\)

Comment: @minthao_2011 Yes, what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 6):

It's somewhat convenient to use Chebyshev polynomials for such purposes. Here, I use the [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html), due to the convenient identity

$$U_n(\cos\,x)=\frac{\sin((n+1)x)}{\sin\,x}$$

Here goes:

```
Integrate[Cos[x]^5, x] /.
       Sin[n_Integer x] :> Sin[x] ChebyshevU[n - 1, Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]^2]] // Expand
   Sin[x] - (2 Sin[x]^3)/3 + Sin[x]^5/5
```

For completeness, the relation $T_n(\cos\,x)=\cos\,nx$ can be similarly exploited. I use that in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9751).

Answer (score 6):

One can use `Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1` and the third argument in `Solve` to eliminate an unwanted dependent variable (i.e. `Cos[x]`) :

```
Expand @ Solve[{L == TrigExpand @ Integrate[Cos[x]^5, x], Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1},
                L, {Cos[x]}]
```

That is useful in more general cases, but with the problem at hand we can observe, that we needn't eliminate `Cos[x]`, e.g. :

```
Expand [Solve[{L= TrigExpand @ Integrate[Cos[x]^5, x], Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1}, L]][[1, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> Sin[x] - (2 Sin[x]^3)/3 + Sin[x]^5/5
> ```

A bit more reliable variation of Vitaliy's approach :

```
TrigExpand[ Integrate[Cos[x]^5, x]] /. Solve[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 == 1, Cos[x]] // 
Simplify // Union
```

Another approach : let's substitute `Cos[x]^n` for an even integer `n` by  `(1 - Sin[x]^2)^(n/2)`, e.g.

```
Simplify[ TrigExpand[ Integrate[Cos[x]^5, x]] /. Cos[x]^n_?EvenQ -> (1 - Sin[x]^2)^(n/2)]
```

**Edit**

To proceed with another problem of the OP remembering that `Integrate[1/(1 + Sin[x] - Cos[x]), x]` and `Log @ Abs[1 + Tan[x/2]]` are not quite equivalent, we have to assume some restrictions of the variable `x`.  Let `x` be real in the range where `Cos[x/2] + Sin[x/2] > 0` and `Cos[x/2] > 0`, e.g. `Pi > x > -Pi/2`, now we have :

```
Simplify[ Integrate[ 1/(1 + Sin[x] + Cos[x]), x], Pi > x > -Pi/2]
```

> ```
> Log[1 + Tan[x/2]]
> ```

```
% // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer does not contain absolute value. I do not understand.

Comment: I added this assumption : `t > -1`, so there is not need for the absolute value.

Comment: In general, how to calculate the given integral? Please help me.

Comment: I want the ansewr is $\ln\left|1 + \tan\dfrac{x}{2}\right|

Comment: @minthao_2011 I hope you see now why you have no absolute value. `Mathematica` treats variables as complex, so only under some assumptions we can get `Log[1 + Tan[x/2]]`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.