# How to decompose a complex expression containing repeated subexpressions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, expression-manipulation

Suppose I have an expression like

```
1/8 + 1/8 Sqrt[1 - 28 (2/(3 (Sqrt[4197] - 9)))^(1/3) + 2 (2/3)^(2/3) (Sqrt[4197] - 9)^(1/3)]
 - 1/2 Sqrt[1/8 - (1/2 (Sqrt[4197] - 9))^(1/3)/(4 3^(2/3)) + 7/(2 2^(2/3) (3 (Sqrt[4197] - 9))^(1/3))
 - 7/(8 Sqrt[1 - 28 (2/(3 (Sqrt[4197] - 9)))^(1/3) + 2 (2/3)^(2/3) (Sqrt[4197] - 9)^(1/3)])]
```

which contains repeated common subexpressions. I am interested in an algorithm that can decompose it into parts of the minimal (or close to minimal) total complexity. The expected output should be something like this:

```
(1 + α - Sqrt[3 - β - 14/α]) / 8 
  /. α -> Sqrt[β]
  /. β -> 1 + 2 γ - 56/(3 γ)  
  /. γ -> (4 Sqrt[4197]/9 - 4)^(1/3)
```

(if you ever worked with [*Maple*](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple), this is similar to how it formats complex output expressions)

Comment: `FullSimplify` looks like it does a better job.

Comment: You've seen `Experimental\`OptimizeExpression`? Although it's meant for numerical applications, its job is indeed CSE.

Comment: @Oleksandr, I think there was a question before that was also answered by ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression[]``; would you happen to remember it?

Comment: @0x4A4D [(25132)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25132/), [(2878)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2878), [(8787)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/)? More closely related to this question: [(9750)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9750/).

Comment: @Oleksandr, I had the second one in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks, `Experimental``OptimizeExpression` is exactly what I need. You could make it into an answer. BTW, how do you put a single backtick in a quoted function name?

Comment: @Oleksandr Do you think this question is a duplicate of one of those?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes. I voted to close as a duplicate of 25132, although arguably all are relevant.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I figured it out - I have to use `` as string delimiters to embed a single ` in it: ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I once tried doing something like this myself, and ended up with a semi-manual process.

```
Clear[branches, tallyBranches];
branches[b_?AtomQ] := {};
branches[b_?NumberQ] := {};
branches[h_[b___]] := Flatten@Append[branches /@ List[b], h[b]];
tallyBranches[e_, k_Integer: 2] := 
  TableForm[Reverse /@ Cases[Tally[branches[e]], {_, t_ /; t >= k}]]
```

Let's take the solution to the cubic as an example:

```
cube = Solve[a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d == 0, x];
```

Generate a table of common branches (with at least 9 occurrences):

```
tallyBranches[cube, 9]

9   1/a
9   b^2
9   -b^2
9   3 a c
9   -b^2+3 a c
12  b^3
12  -2 b^3
12  9 a b c
12  a^2
12  -27 a^2 d
```

Then we can manually pick a branch to substitute:

```
cube2 = cube //. -b^2 + 3 a c -> α;
```

And then repeat:

```
tallyBranches[cube2, 6];
```

Etc..

After three substitutions we end up with something like this:

$$\left\{\left\{x\to -\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \alpha }{3 a \sqrt[3]{\gamma
   }}-\frac{b}{3 a}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{\gamma }}{3 \sqrt[3]{2}
   a}\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \alpha }{3\
   2^{2/3} a \sqrt[3]{\gamma }}-\frac{b}{3 a}-\frac{\left(1-i
   \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\gamma }}{6 \sqrt[3]{2} a}\right\},\left\{x\to
   \frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \alpha }{3\ 2^{2/3} a \sqrt[3]{\gamma
   }}-\frac{b}{3 a}-\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\gamma }}{6
   \sqrt[3]{2} a}\right\}\right\}$$

where $\alpha =3 a c-b^2$, $\beta =-27 a^2 d+9 a b c-2 b^3$, and $\gamma =\sqrt{4 \alpha ^3+\beta ^2}+\beta$.