# Fast evaluation

Tags: performance-tuning

I have a particularly nasty expression (many of them),

[image]

Full simplify is also not an option.

Ideally, I would like to evaluate this function (preferably fast) for around 1500 different values its argument. The problem is that, if I first construct the numerical list of the arguments and then use

```
func./list
```

the evaluation takes too long. Also, alternatively, I've tried to evaluate the function in a table, but also much too long.

EDIT:

More information:

```
Frenorm[Px_, Py_, Pz_] := 
 a1s (Px^2 + Py^2) + a3s Pz^2 + a11s (Px^4 + Py^4) + a33s Pz^4 + 
  a13s (Px^2 Pz^2 + Py^2 Pz^2) + 
  a12s (Px^2 Py^2) + alpha111 (Px^6 + Py^6 + 
     Pz^6) + alpha112 (Px^4 (Py^2 + Pz^2) + Pz^4 (Px^2 + Py^2) + 
     Py^4 (Px^2 + Pz^2)) + alpha123 Px^2 Py^2 Pz^2 + mu

acPhaseSolSet = {Sqrt[p1], Sqrt[p3]} /. Solve[{Expand[D[Frenorm[Sqrt[p1], 0, Sqrt[p3]], p1]] == 0, Expand[D[Frenorm[Sqrt[p1], 0, Sqrt[p3]], p3]] == 0}, {p1, p3}]

acPhaseEnergy =  Table[Frenorm[Px, 0, Pz] /. {Px -> acPhaseSolSet[[j]][[1]], Pz -> acPhaseSolSet[[j]][[2]]}, {j, 1, Length[acPhaseSolSet]}]
```

Here, `acPhaseEnergy`, yields a result (there are five solutions) that is so long (above) that won't let you efficiently (and rapidly) input a list value of {a1s, a3s, ...}. I would like to put in 1500 lists of different numbers of a1s, etc and get a grid of energy values.

Ie, for example, maybe these values would be

```
list = {a1s -> -4.01483*10^8, a3s -> -1.92393*10^8, a11s -> 3.3416*10^8, 
 a33s -> 4.99091*10^7, a13s -> 8.10182*10^8, alpha111->-4.0*10^7, alpha112->35.0*10^6, alpha123->-3.0*10^7, 
 a12s -> 1.09218*10^9, mu -> 1.81818*10^7}
```

so one could try

```
acPhaseEnergy/.list
```

Comment: Try `Compile`. I would have expanded on this if you only had provided copyable code.

Comment: Maybe try `Dispatch` on `list`?

Comment: Henrik, the copyable code is much too long. Sorry

Comment: You could try using `Block`, as in `Block[{a1s=1, a11s=2, ..}, func]`.

Comment: Not much to go on from this description.

Comment: maybe have a look here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26527/2079

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`` Experimental`OptimizeExpression `` gives a significant speed-up.  After injecting the values, `First` will let the optimized expression evaluate:

```
opt = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[acPhaseEnergy];
opt /. list // First // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.002094, {1.95313*10^9 + 3.446*10^9 I, 
  1.95313*10^9 - 3.446*10^9 I, -5.38374*10^7, 2.49635*10^12}}
*)

acPhaseEnergy /. list // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{7.05487, {1.95313*10^9 + 3.446*10^9 I, 
  1.95313*10^9 - 3.446*10^9 I, -5.38374*10^7, 2.49635*10^12}}
*)
```

*To evaluate many times:*

It helps if the values are packed arrays.  This can be accomplished with `` Develop`ToPackedArray[values] ``.  Many functions create or preserve packed arrays.  For instance `RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, 1500]` generates 1500 values in a packed array, so that using `ToPackedArray` in `` Developer`ToPackedArray[RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, 1500]] `` is unnecessary.

```
Block[{n = 1500},
  list = {a1s -> -4.01483*10^8 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n], 
    a3s -> -1.92393*10^8 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n], 
    a11s -> 3.3416*10^8 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n], 
    a33s -> 4.99091*10^7 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n], 
    a13s -> 8.10182*10^8 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n], 
    alpha111 -> -4.0*10^7 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n], 
    alpha112 -> 35.0*10^6 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n], 
    alpha123 -> -3.0*10^7 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n], 
    a12s -> 1.09218*10^9 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n], 
    mu -> 1.81818*10^7 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n]}
  ];

opt /. list // First // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.229654, {4, 1500}}  *)
```

To get the values in their proper order use `Transpose[opt /. list // First]`.

Comment: Experimental`OptimizeExpression was definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that

1. the lengthy code is contained in the variable `prettylengthyandexpensivecode`;
2. you have a list `vars` containing all symbols in `prettylengthyandexpensivecode`;
3. all parameters are supposed to be complex numbers; and
4. no special functions are involved in `prettylengthyandexpensivecode`,

you can try to compile. With the provided data, this could look as follows:

```
vars = {a1s, a3s, a11s, a33s, a13s, alpha111, alpha112, alpha123, 
  a12s, mu};
prettylengthyandexpensivecode = acPhaseEnergy
cf = With[{
   ccode = N[prettylengthyandexpensivecode],
   cvars = Map[var \[Function] {var, _Complex}, vars]
   },
  Compile[
   Evaluate[cvars],
   ccode,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ]
  ]
```

Then, if you have a matrix `data` of real numbers where the $i$th row contains the bazillion values of `vars[[i]]` you want to try, just execute

```
cf@@data
```

Using the example data from Michael E2, we can process about 1.5 million data sets per second:

```
Block[{n = 1500000},
  list = {
    a1s -> -4.01483*10^8 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n],
    a3s -> -1.92393*10^8 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n],
    a11s -> 3.3416*10^8 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n],
    a33s -> 4.99091*10^7 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n],
    a13s -> 8.10182*10^8 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n],
    alpha111 -> -4.0*10^7 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n],
    alpha112 -> 35.0*10^6 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n],
    alpha123 -> -3.0*10^7 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n],
    a12s -> 1.09218*10^9 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n],
    mu -> 1.81818*10^7 RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, n]}
  ];

cf @@ list[[All, 2]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.10661

However, another drawback of this method is that only computations in machine precision are possible within a `LibraryFunction`. I get numerical errors frequently with this random data. In these cases, the `CompiledFunction` `cf` is clever enough to switch to a standard Mathematica function as fallback (so the results should be accurate but not as fast as with a `LibraryFunction`).

By the way: As far as I know, `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression `` is also used internally by `Compile`.

Comment: I've edited my question to include minimal working code

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in my comment, using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) instead of [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll) provides a 4-fold speed up:

```
acPhaseEnergy /. list //AbsoluteTiming

Hold@@list /. Rule->Set /. Hold[s__] :> Block[{s}, acPhaseEnergy] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {6.36568, {1.95313*10^9 + 3.446*10^9 I, 
>     1.95313*10^9 - 3.446*10^9 I, -5.38374*10^7, 2.49635*10^12}}
>
> {1.56335, {1.95313*10^9 + 3.446*10^9 I, 
>     1.95313*10^9 - 3.446*10^9 I, -5.38374*10^7, 2.49635*10^12}}

**Update**

Another factor of 6 speedup can be obtained by doing the replacements in stages. For example:

```
t = Hold@@list /. Rule->Set /. Hold[s__] :> Block[{s}, acPhaseSolSet]; //AbsoluteTiming

Table[Frenorm[p[[1]], 0, p[[2]]] /. list, {p, t}] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.256775, Null}
>
> {0.000228, {1.95313*10^9 + 3.446*10^9 I, 
>     1.95313*10^9 - 3.446*10^9 I, -5.38374*10^7, 2.49635*10^12}}

in agreement with the previous results.

**Update 2**

We can combine @MichaelE2's nice approach using `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression `` and my [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) and 2-step ideas to improve speed further:

```
opt = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[acPhaseSolSet]; //RepeatedTiming

t = Hold@@list /. Rule->Set /. Hold[s__] :> Block[{s}, First @ opt]; //RepeatedTiming

Table[Frenorm[p[[1]], 0, p[[2]]] /. list, {p, t}] //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.182, Null}
>
> {0.00032, Null}
>
> {0.0002, {1.95313*10^9 + 3.446*10^9 I, 
>     1.95313*10^9 - 3.446*10^9 I, -5.38374*10^7, 2.49635*10^12}}

Compare this to not using my [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) and 2-step ideas:

```
opt = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[acPhaseEnergy]; //RepeatedTiming

opt /. list //First //RepeatedTiming
```

> {1.09, Null}
>
> {0.0018, {1.95313*10^9 + 3.446*10^9 I, 
>     1.95313*10^9 - 3.446*10^9 I, -5.38374*10^7, 2.49635*10^12}}

It takes more time to optimize the `acPhaseEnergy` expression, and using `/.` is about 3-4 times slower.