# Why won't Mathematica give a prettier expression for this really simple algebraic expression?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

As  a result of some lengthy calculations, Mathematica gave me the following expresssion:

$$
\frac{xy^2+(1 + y)\sqrt{1 + y(2 + y + xy)}}{(1 + y)^2}
$$

I tried all sorts of simplifications, but none of them did anything useful. How can I get Mathematica to turn this into

$$
x(\frac{y}{1+y})^2+\sqrt{1+x(\frac{y}{1+y})^2}?
$$

I know that simplicity and prettiness is not always objective, but I almost didn't see that my expression has the form `f(x,y/(1+y))` which is actually super useful for my next steps (and I have a bunch of expressions that are even more complicated that I believe hide some valuable treasures like this)
Here is the code I tried
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/17534701-7be6-443e-b7c5-f8564e04d225

```
Assuming[{x>0,y>0},FullSimplify[(x y^2+(1 + y) Sqrt[1 + y(2 + y + x y)])/(1 + y)^2]]
```

> (x y^2 + (1 + y) Sqrt[1 + y (2 + y + x y)])/(1 + y)^2

PS: the site always complains about code that is not formatted as code when I try to post maths. On previous questions, other users could just edit the code bits out, in case someone wants to give it a try? See ["Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" with math blocks](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as-code-with)

Comment: `xy` is not the same as `x*y` or `x y`. You need a star or a space between `x` and `y` to indicate multiplication.

Comment: Please copy-paste what *Mathematica* actually spits out instead of converting to $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @Roman I used the correct mathematica code

Comment: @Roman you can click the link to wolframcloud. I also added the exact Mathematica code I tried to the question.

Comment: @Roman thanks for editing the question. This is really frustrating...

Comment: You're welcome. The triple backticks messed up the formatting.

Comment: @Roman I had to add the triple backticks because the site doesn't let me post without them. It says "There seems to be code not properly formatted as code in your question." and it doesn't let me post the question. Hence, I always add backticks around every math bit in my questions. Even now after your edit, if I try to make a pure text change, I can't do it because I get the same message.

Comment: This question has been discussed several times, and there is no catch-all answer. However, reading https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26527/61597 and its own linked questions may help you along.

Comment: @lirtosiast I can't get anything helpful out of those

Comment: @lirtosiast I don't think I will need a catch-all answer. Anything that works for this simple example would probably also work for the other expressions I am currently interested in, since they appear in the same kind of calculations. There must be a way to get "the world's definitive system for modern technical computing" to perform algebraic simplifications every teenager could do.

Answer (score 2):

```
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[(x y^2 + (1 + y) Sqrt[
  1 + y (2 + y + x y)])/(1 + y)^2]
(*
  Experimental`OptimizedExpression[Block[{Compile`$2}, Compile`$2 = 1 + y;
      (x*y^2 + Compile`$2*Sqrt[1 + y*(2 + y + x*y)])/Compile`$2^2]]
*)
```

This figures out that `1+y` is common, and pulls it out of the main expression. For a more complicated expression, it probably would see more such patterns. However, `OptimizeExpression` is about computational efficiency, not human insight. Human insight requires human reasoning here.

Comment: I tried that before but since it doesn't figure out that there is a (1+y)^2 in the square root though, it's not very helpful

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, it is hard to do this universally.

But you could write some specialized rules and apply them. This below is just an example. This is not meant to be universal solution.

```
ClearAll[x, y, any, any1];
rule2 = (1 + 2 x_ + x_^2) :> (1 + x)^2;
rule1 = (Sqrt[any_]/any1_) :> Sqrt[Simplify[(Expand[any] /. rule2)/any1^2]];
expr = (x y^2 + (1 + y) Sqrt[1 + y (2 + y + x y)])/(1 + y)^2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Collect[expr, Denominator[expr]] /. rule1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `rule1` above which move term under the sqrt, as in $\frac{1}{x}$ to $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ is valid only when `x` is positive of course.

Comment: Appreciate the input, but what I gather from this and the other answer is "Mathematica can't do this".

Answer (score 0):

A substitution would work: setting $z=x\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)^2$,

```
Assuming[y > 0 && z > 0,
  (x y^2 + (1 + y) Sqrt[1 + y (2 + y + x y)])/(1 + y)^2 /. x -> z ((1 + y)/y)^2 // FullSimplify]
(*    z + Sqrt[1 + z]    *)
```

Comment: Figuring out that` z=x(y/(1+y))^2` is the right substitution here is as hard as doing everything by hand to begin with, and I believe the same is true for the more complicated expressions I am facing